# PHP fetch data from mysql and put it in <select>

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone please tell me , how to fetch names from mysql through php and then put all those names in hmtl select tag for user to choose one name

Comment: do some research:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940548/populate-html-select-with-array-data-from-mysql-in-php

Answer (score 1):

use a foreach

```
echo "<select name='username'>"; 
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
  {
  $user=array( $row['fieldname']);
  foreach($user as $val)
   {
      echo "<option value='\$val\'>".$val."</option>";
   }  
  }
 echo "</select>";
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](http://www.easynewsandfactz.blogspot.in/).

Hints are

```
    // sql connection here
    $query="SELECT * FROM emp";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($result)
    {
      echo $r[0];
      // all the row that u want to fetch
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).  It let's you access the data from SQL which you can then output in a select.